# Computing the centroid of an "ellipsoid slice"

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I want to compute the centroid of a body of the following form:
$$
E\cap H_1\cap \cdots \cap H_T
$$
where:

- $E$ is an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^d$: $E = \{x = c + Bu | u^T u \leq 1\}$, where $c$ is the ellipsoid center and $B$ is a matrix.
- $H_1,\ldots,H_T$ are half-spaces.

Can this be done in time polynomial in $d$ (the dimension) and $T$ (the number of half-spaces)?

<sub>The motivation to this question comes from the [ellipsoid method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method). In that method, after intersecting the current ellipsoid with a half-space, we find another ellipsoid that contains the resulting "half-ellipsoid". I would like to understand whether this last step is essential, or maybe we could just keep the half-ellipsoid and find its centroid, etc., without covering them with ellipsoids.</sub>